# VBA - Is it possible to pass an Object's property as an argument in a method?

Tags: vba, object, methods, properties

I'm pretty used to VBA, not that much for Objects though and I'm hitting a wall right now...

My config class has almost 100 properties, so I'll not spam them here as the details doesn't really matter for my question.

I **hoped to code a duplicate function**, to **create multiple objects from one and then assign different values for a specific property of each new objects** (add new elements to the configurations, so it generates new configs), that would look like this :

```
Public Function Duplicate(SrcCfg As Config, PropertyName As String, Properties As String) As Collection
Dim Cc As Collection, _
    Cfg As Config, _
    TotalNumber As Integer, _
    A() As String

Set Cc = New Collection
A = Split(Properties, "/")
TotalNumber = UBound(A)

For i = 0 To TotalNumber
    'Create a copy of the source object
    Set Cfg = SrcCfg.Copy
    'Set the property for that particular copy
    Cfg.PropertyName = A(i)
    'Add that copy to the collection
    Cc.Add ByVal Cfg
Next i

    Duplicate = Cc
End Function
```

But I'm not sure that a collection is the best output (as I'll take the results and incorporate them into another master collection), so I'm open to suggestions.

And I'm pretty sure that **we can't pass a Property as an argument** (I spent quite some times looking for a solution for this...) and I don't know what to do about it as this would be super practical for me. So if there is a solution or a workaround, I'll gladly try it!

Here is the rest of my methods :

```
Friend Sub SetConfig(SrcConfig As Config)
    Config = SrcConfig
End Sub

Public Function Copy() As Config
    Dim Result As Config
    Set Result = New Config
    Call Result.SetConfig(Config)
    Set Copy = Result
End Function
```

---

---

### Final code to duplicate object :

---

Working smoothly :

```
Private Cfg As Config

Friend Sub SetConfig(SrcConfig As Config)
    Set Cfg = SrcConfig
End Sub

Public Function Copy() As Config
    Dim Result As Config
    Set Result = New Config
    Call Result.SetConfig(Cfg)
    Set Copy = Result
End Function

Public Function Duplicate(PropertyName As String, Properties As String) As Collection
Dim Cc As Collection, _
    Cfg As Config, _
    TotalNumber As Integer, _
    A() As String

Set Cc = New Collection
A = Split(Properties, "/")
TotalNumber = UBound(A)

For i = 0 To TotalNumber
    'Create a copy of the source object
    Set Cfg = Me.Copy
    'Set the property for that particular copy
    CallByName Cfg, PropertyName, VbLet, A(i)
    'Add that copy to the collection
    Cc.Add Cfg
Next i

    Set Duplicate = Cc
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe see Scott's answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805475/assignment-of-objects-in-vb6/4805812#4805812

Comment: @TimWilliams : Thx, I got started with this answer, to create the `.copy` method and it was indeed really useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually got it right, including the types (`String`).

Just replace your

```
Cfg.PropertyName = A(i)
```

with

```
CallByName Cfg, PropertyName, vbLet, A(i)
```

The property name must be passed as a string, not a reference or a lambda or anything, so no type safety or compiler aid here. You will have a runtime error if you misspell the name.

As for the return type, VBA does not have lists, so a collection is generally fine, but because in your particular case you know in advance how many objects you will be returning, you can declare an array:

```
Dim Cc() As Config
ReDim Cc(1 to TotalNumber)
```

You could declare an array in any case, but if you didn't know the total number, you'd be reallocating it on every iteration.

Comment: Thx for your quick answer, I love to read that it IS possible! <3 My weekend will be far more enjoyable! :) I'll try this soon and validate answer then if that's not a problem for you!

Comment: I tested it and it worked awesomely! :)
Thx for input and I'll post my updated code so that it'll be clearer for people when they come

Comment: Just a little question as I'm not sure about this, but I use a custom object as argument and yet it is an object method, so can I change `Set Cfg = SrcCfg.Copy` to `Set Cfg = Me.Copy` and get rid of the argument? It seems pretty logical but it is the first time I'm really working with VBA objects