# Cloning a Collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have two collections - `collection1` and `collection2`

`collection1` has a number of class objects in it and I am trying to fill `collection2` with copies of the same objects using the following command:

```
Set collection2 = collection1
```

This doesn't give me the desired result though, because when I use

```
collection2.Remove 1
```

It removes the object at index 1 from **both** collections.

Below is the full code, which I hoped would output `10` objects in `collection1` after removing one from collection2

```
Sub test()
    Dim collection1 As Collection
    Dim collection2 As Collection
    Dim testObj As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set collection1 = New Collection
    Set collection2 = New Collection

    For i = 1 To 10
        collection1.Add testObj
    Next i

    Set collection2 = collection1
    collection2.Remove 1
    Debug.Print collection1.Count
End Sub
```

---

I tried the code below and it works but I'm looking to avoid filling both collections one by one if possible:

```
...
For i = 1 To 10
    collection1.Add testObj
    collection2.Add testObj
Next i
...
```

The reason I'm not so keen on this option is because ultimately I intend to use multiple collections, manipulating them and taking copies at various points so I would end up with lots of for loops in my code, rather than just one.

Comment: I think you mean `Set collection2 = collection1` perhaps...

Comment: There is no copy function for a collection.  This: Set collection2 = collection2 just makes a second reference to the Collection object.  Your best bet is what you want to avoid IE filling both at the same time.

Comment: @Rdster that was just a typo, corrected now

Comment: @Sorceri, I added some detail as to why I didn't want to fill them both at the same time - ultimately I wouldn't be filling the collections at the same time but a number of different times

Comment: its not possible.  Collections in VBA  are reference types. read this : http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm

Comment: You can create a function to "clone" a collection and return the copy (as long as you don't require keys)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't even create a clone function for Collections because there isn't a way to access the keys.  If you need a clone-able generic container, use a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805475/assignment-of-objects-in-vb6/4805812#4805812

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *I am trying to fill collection2 with copies of the same objects using the following command:*
>
> ```
> Set collection2 = collection1
> ```

Yet that's not what that command does. The `Set` keyword doesn't "copy objects", and doesn't automagically know (or even care) that it's dealing with a `Collection` object that contains items.

The `Set` keyword **assigns a reference**. Nothing more, nothing less.

So what `Set collection2 = collection1` does, is, literally:

> *Take the pointer for the `collection1` object, and replace whatever `collection2` is referring to with that.*

That `Set` instruction is effectively discarding the object reference that was created here:

```
Set collection2 = New Collection
```

`Set` does not "copy objects" and cannot "fill" collection2 - you're *overwriting* its object reference, making the `collection2` variable point to the **same object** as the `collection1` variable does.

And since both pointers point to the *same object*... removing an item using either `Collection` is indeed going to be removing it from "both" collections, ...because there's only one collection object involved.

---

The hidden (undocumented?) `ObjPtr` function can help shed some light on what's going on:

```
Set collection1 = New Collection
Debug.Print "collection1: " & ObjPtr(collection1)

Set collection2 = New Collection
Debug.Print "collection2: " & ObjPtr(collection2)

'the debug output contains 2 different addresses at this point

Set collection2 = collection1
Debug.Print "collection1: " & ObjPtr(collection1)
Debug.Print "collection2: " & ObjPtr(collection2)

'now the debug output clearly shows that 
'both collection1 and collection2 are pointing to the same object
```

---

If you need copies of a collection, you need a function that takes a collection and returns a brand new object:

```
Public Function CopyCollection(ByVal source As Collection) As Collection
    Dim result As New Collection
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In source
        result.Add item
    Next
    Set CopyCollection = result
End Function
```

[As already noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41065287/set-collection2-collection1-not-creating-independent-collections#comment69337838_41065287) though, this will only work if your collections aren't keyed. Because of how limited a `Collection` is (you can't iterate its keys), you'll have to use a `Scripting.Dictionary` instead, if you need to clone a keyed collection.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you dont need to     `Dim collection1 As Collection` and     `Set collection1 = New Collection`. This can be replaced by     `Dim collection1 As New Collection`

Now, what you are doing is making the collection2 to contain the collection1. Its like putting lots of caps on a box (collection1) and then putting this box inside another box (collection2).

The alternative is to either fill both of them at the same time or do a code to copy the contents like

```
for i = 1 to collection1.count
    collection2.add collection1.item(i)
next i
```

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx doesn't recommend auto-instancing objects, would you disagree?

Comment: The experience I have with collections is with my [Deck shuffling](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148546/deck-shuffle-and-drawing-cards) and it gave no problems for me yet.

Comment: Also, the first part of the answer is not what you asked for, so feel free to ignore.