# Set custom variable type by value

Tags: vba, excel, reference

Example:

```
Custom Class "myClass"
```

How to create new variable of "myClass" type:

```
Dim var1 as myClass

set var1 = new myClass
```

What I want:
After manipulating `var1`'s properties, create `var2` as a copy of `var1`'s current state.

What I  tried:

(assuming `var1` has already been manipulated)

```
dim var2 as myClass

set var2 = var1
```

However this ended up in what I think is a set by reference value because whatever I did to `var2` after this point, also changed `var1`. How can I set `var2` to be equal to `var1` by value?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805475/assignment-of-objects-in-vb6/4805812#4805812) may answer your question. Not a quick solution though.

Comment: You are discovering the true meaning and functionality of the `Set` keyword. `var1` and `var2` are two pointers to the **same** object reference. If you need two distinct objects, make two distinct objects - you need a way to copy their internal state, VB can't guess that for you.