# Copy an object without reference in VBA

Tags: vba, object, reference, set, copy

I have trouble with Object Variables in VBA. Is it possible to just copy object variables without any reference?

Here the class module "clstest"

```
Option Explicit

Public x As Single
```

And here is my Sub:

```
Sub CopyWithoutReference()

Dim standard As New clstest
Set standard = New clstest

Dim different As New clstest

standard.x = 20

Set different = standard
different.x = 30

MsgBox "I want standard.x to be 20 and not 30"
MsgBox standard.x
MsgBox different.x
```

I want standard.x to keep its value and not change if different.x changes.
I read this Article here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement
And it says:

"Because such variables are references to the object rather than copies of the object, any change in the object is reflected in all variables that refer to it."

But i don't know how to obviate this problem. Anyone of you know how to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `clone` method to the class, so I have

My class

```
Public x As Integer

Public Function Clone() As Class1
    Set Clone = New Class1
    Clone.x = x
End Function
```

My module

```
Sub a()

Dim o As Class1
Dim o2 As Class1

Set o = New Class1
o.x = 20

Set o2 = o.Clone
o2.x = 500

Debug.Print o.x, o2.x

End Sub
```

-------------------   COPY ALLL AT ONCE IDEA ---------------------

New class

```
Public Properties_ As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Properties_ = New Scripting.Dictionary
End Sub

Public Sub Set_Property(strPropertyName As String, varProperty As Variant)
    If Properties_.Exists(strPropertyName) Then
        Properties_(strPropertyName) = varProperty
    Else
        Properties_.Add strPropertyName, varProperty
    End If
End Sub

Public Function Clone_() As Class1

    Set Clone_ = New Class1

    For i = 0 To Properties_.Count - 1
        Clone_.Set_Property CStr(Properties_.Keys()(i)), Properties_.Items()(i)

    Next i

End Function
```

New Module

```
Public Sub x()

Dim o1 As Class1
Dim o2 As Class1

Set o1 = New Class1

o1.Set_Property "Date", Now
o1.Set_Property "Name", "Test Name"

Set o2 = o1.Clone_

o2.Set_Property "Date", DateSerial(2000, 1, 1)

Debug.Print o1.Properties_("Date"), o2.Properties_("Date")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my code i have a lot more Properties than just one (x). Is i possible to clone all properties at once?

Comment: You will need to be a little fancy, maybe create a dictionary or collection in your class, called `Properties` and may be iterate through these.  Setting the new collection to be the old, may not work that easy.

Comment: @Charlex  I've added a quick attempt

Comment: That answered my question, thank you for this solution.That answered my question, thank you for this solution.

Comment: So pretty much, following this pattern, every object could set its own properties? E.g., `o2.Set_Property "SomeNewProperty", 19999`. This does not look close to OOP.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer about VB6 is pretty good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805812/5448626), the implementation of the [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) and the way to refer to the properties through a type in VBA is what achieves the copying of the properties.

---

An object of type Employee with properties `Salary`, `Age` and `RelevantExperience` is created. Then a new object, copying the old one with the function `.Copy` is created. The new object initially has the same properties, but we may choose to change some of them. In the code below the **Experience** and the **Age** is changed, the **Salary** is not mentioned, thus it stays the same:

```
Dim newEmp As Employee
Dim oldEmp As Employee

Set newEmp = New Employee
With newEmp
    .Salary = 100
    .Age = 22
    .RelevantExperience = 1
End With

Set oldEmp = newEmp.Copy
With oldEmp
    'Salary is the same as in the NewEmp
    .Age = 99
    .RelevantExperience = 10
End With
```

This is the result:

[image]

The old Employee has the same salary, "inherited" by the new employee, when he is copied. The Experience and the Age are different.

**Full implementation**

In a module:

```
Type MyMemento
    Salary As Double
    Age As Long
    RelevantExperience As Long
End Type

Sub Main()

    Dim newEmp As Employee
    Dim oldEmp As Employee

    Set newEmp = New Employee
    With newEmp
        .Salary = 100
        .Age = 22
        .RelevantExperience = 1
    End With

    Set oldEmp = newEmp.Copy
    With oldEmp
        'Salary is inherited, thus the same
        .Age = 99
        .RelevantExperience = 10
    End With

    Debug.Print "Salary"; vbCrLf; newEmp.Salary, oldEmp.Salary
    Debug.Print "Experience"; vbCrLf; newEmp.RelevantExperience, oldEmp.RelevantExperience
    Debug.Print "Age"; vbTab; vbCrLf; newEmp.Age, oldEmp.Age

End Sub
```

In a class module, called `Employee`:

```
Private Memento As MyMemento

Friend Sub SetMemento(NewMemento As MyMemento)
    Memento = NewMemento
End Sub

Public Function Copy() As Employee
    Dim Result As Employee
    Set Result = New Employee        
    Result.SetMemento Memento
    Set Copy = Result        
End Function

Public Property Get Salary() As Double
    Salary = Memento.Salary
End Property    
Public Property Let Salary(value As Double)
    Memento.Salary = value
End Property

Public Property Get Age() As Long
    Age = Memento.Age
End Property    
Public Property Let Age(value As Long)
    Memento.Age = value
End Property

Public Property Get RelevantExperience() As Long
    RelevantExperience = Memento.RelevantExperience
End Property    
Public Property Let RelevantExperience(value As Long)
    Memento.RelevantExperience = value
End Property
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thank you! Unfortunately VBA itself does not provide something like an argument where you just say "Reference = True/False"

Comment: @Charlex - welcome. VBA does not have a lot of things, but one may always build them. It is funnier this way! :D